# C# DataGridView Как заполнить целый столбец значениями

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

для заполнения отдельной ячейки я пишу так:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[3].Value = 123123123;
```

а как заполнить весь третий столбец значениями `123123123`? Я знаю, что через цикл, но как это сделать? Опишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса - вы пишете, что знаете и тут же спрашиваете - как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял о чем вопрос, то как-то так:

```
    for (int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = 123123123;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Третий столбец это: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[`**`2`**`].Value`. Счет начинается с нуля.

Заполнить столбец можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = 123123123;
}
```

или так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1[2, i].Value = 123123123;
}
```